# Source Tree not getting synchronized with bit bucket on deletion of branches from Bit Bucket UI

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

In a scenario a branch is deleted from web in BitBucket, when I look into source tree the branch is still available there (After pull, refresh)..

It can also be seen while performing Pull operation in `"remote branch to Pull:"` option but with a different name like: `"refs/remotes/origin/feature/MY_BRANCH_NAME"`.

I was under impression, if any branch gets deleted from anywhere(Other than Source Tree) source tree must be updated automatically with current available branches (After Pull). But this is not happening with my case.

**My concern is:**

1. Why source tree is still showing the branches which have been
   deleted?
2. What is this `refs/remotes/origin/feature/MY_BRANCH_NAME` name means?
3. I am doing something wrong here?

Source Tree version:`3.2.6`

OS: `Windows 10 64`